# Installation hangs up on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I'm trying to install 14.04 on a HP/Compaq laptop with 1.5G RAM and a 25G hard drive.  It had Windows XP on it and it was full of viruses so I figured I'd experiment with UBUNTU.
I downloaded 14.04, 32 bit version, burned a Disc Image DVD and popped it into the laptop.
I opted for doing a full erase of XP and installing 14.04, I checked the boxes for 'install updates' and 'install' some mp3 app.
Anyway, three times now the install hangs up at the same exact spot.....'Configuring bcmwl-kernel-source (i386)'.  I've let it hang there for days and it never gets any further.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You can try this suggestion http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2182821&p=12843592#post12843592

Comment: Possibly the DVD is faulty. That is why it stops at the same random spot each time. Try burning another DVD at a lower speed.

Comment: Ok, but I've tried two DVD's so far.  Although both were burned at the same speed on the same machine.

Comment: I don't thing the DVD is corrupted thats unlikely. Look at the link that i have posted above there are the same issue.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it again without checking the boxes.

Comment: Actually, the first time I tried to install it I did it without checking the boxes.  The install seemed to go fine but the laptop would not shut down when I hit 'shut down'.  I waited over 24 hours for the laptop to shut itself off but it never did so I tried reinstalling.  Sorry, forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue. I say a bug report that looks unresolved: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1307744
I unchecked "Download Updates While Installing" and "Install this Third Party Software". After unchecking these the install went through fine.Previously I had checked these and that is when it hung on me. After your install hook a cat 5 cable up to your router and then google how to reinstall the needed driver.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and got it working by:

- Use the 32-bit version (even though the system is 64-bit)
- Making a fresh installation drive (the old one may be corrupted somehow)
- Not connecting to the internet (this seemed to crash)
- Not installing 3rd-party tools (not sure if this is necessary, but you can do it manually later anyway)
- Choosing the "Something else..." option and setting up partitions manually, since the installation didn't seem to make the right partitions

I'm definitely not saying this should be done for every installation, but it seems a safe choice in case the default settings don't work.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I had the same issue, but gave it some debugging.
At least in my case it turned out to be a combination of
a) slow internet access
b) a lot of updates to the image I wanted to install

Eventually the "hang" was just downloading/installing a lot of packages.
To check if this is true in your case, you could do the same as me:
1. go to console "CTRL+F1"
2. login (ubuntu/blank)
3. tail -f /var/log/syslog

In my case there I saw a lot of installations/downloads going on, after those finished it went on as usual.