# Ubuntu Minimal Install - No desktop environment?

Tags: desktop-environments, mate

Note: I installed Ubuntu Minimal because of a bug in (apparently) all *buntu 15.04, 14.04 and 14.10 versions which cause the installer to hang when installing on my system before the partitioning stage... See these questions...

Example: [Installation hangs up on 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459527/installation-hangs-up-on-14-04)

But I am not running on a laptop and that question did not help fix that problem, so I resorted to the minimal (text based) install.

## Question

I have installed Ubuntu using the Ubuntu Minimal Install image (~40MB) on a USB disk.

When I boot my computer I get the message on tty7 (CTRL+ALT+F7)

```
starting version 219
```

That's it, there's nothing else there. (What does this message mean?)

I figured there was no desktop environment, since one wasn't specified during the install process. (I'm sure the installed used to ask for a desktop environment option? Has this been removed from the install process?)

So I ran

```
sudo apt-get install mate-core
sudo reboot
```

Still nothing, same message appears. I can log into any of the other tty's, but if I run `startx`, I get the error:

```
The program `startx` is not currently installed. ... install package xinit
```

Do I want to install `xinit`? Or do I need to install `mdm` service or something?

Graphics card is a GTX 260 although I don't think this is of any relevance.

The question tagged as a duplicate is of no relevance to me. I acquired this problem through a completely different set of steps. (This is a new install, not a replacement of 1 desktop environment with another.) In addition, the fault is not "that I see this message" the fault is that I don't have a desktop environment. My question about `starting version 219` is merely something I happen to be interested in.

## Update

I believe I have no desktop manager installed? The file `/etc/X11/default-desktop-manager` does not exist. How can I fix this?

## Update 2

Okay so I might be breaking my system now... but I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install mdm
```

Because I figured I need a display manager of some sort. (Not sure what it is or does, but it's probably important.)

This didn't seem to help, so I then tried:

```
sudo apt-get install xinit
```

Which installed a *vast* number of packages.

I now have a desktop environment, but it's *broken*. When I run `startx` I get a desktop environment... but it looks like the 1990's linux desktop environments. (That sort of blocky grey everything.) I think this might be a fallback desktop environment for when you screw up your mate/gnome/unity/kde one?

What should I do now?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29913/discussion-on-question-by-user3728501-ubuntu-minimal-install-no-desktop-enviro).

Answer (score 2):

Indeed there is no desktop environment on a minimal install. You can install it just typing

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

The dependencies should be resolved automatically, so it will be a long list of packages.